# Why shouldn’t I add additional profile fields directly to my django.contrib.auth.models.User table?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

To add additional user profile information in Django, it seems that using `AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL` is the suggested way to go.

However, are there any disadvantages of adding additional profile fields directly to the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` table? To me, this seems to be much easier/straightforward (though granted, I don't yet have a grasp on using signals).

Are there any very strong *practical* reasons against doing it this way?

Comment: Well, you have to go to `contrib.auth` and fix your `User` model each time you update Django.

Comment: @rebus: not if you monkey-patch the User model, instead of editing the source.

Comment: @Matthew I agree, but when talking about best practices I would avoid monkey patching too. `AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL` still sound as better solution IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of following reasons:

**Django updates**

You have to update your `contrib.auth` each time you update Django so you don't break your application, and this is a maintenance nightmare. Using `AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL` method makes Django updates painless while it provides ability to add new information to `User`. This is called [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) i belive.

**`User` dependant applications**

3rd party application that heavily rely on `User` having the exact same fields will fail if you for example add fields to `User` model that are declared as `NOT NULL` or remove some that are expected to be there.

Further reading about `AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL`:

- [James Bennett's tips on extending User model](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/)
- [Django official docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)
- [deprecation of AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ddeff3e12614548) thread on django-developers mailing list

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it is more maintainable to use profiles. Based on my understanding what is advised against is making changes that will be removed once you update your Django version. If you modify `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model, then the changes will be removed once you update, or you will be responsibly for merging any changes done if any. On the other hand if the code lives in your application such as the profiles does then it's easier to manage. Based on that if you find another method that achieves the same, or if you don't see it as a maintenance hassle then It should not matter much one way or the other.